# Dequeue: put, get from back and front "IN C LANGUAGE"

Tags: list

I'm trying to make dequeue with linked list which i can add random elements from queue's front or back and want to get and delete them randomly. My program runs but idk why, in somewhere it fails. Randomly it has segmentation fault and i can't find the problem. Here is my code:

MY FUNCTIONS:

```
void dequeue_put_back(struct DeQueue *q, void *elem)
{
        struct Node *n = new_node(elem, q->elem_size);

        if (q->head == NULL) {
                q->head = n;
        q->head->prev = NULL;
                q->tail = n;
        q->tail->prev = head;
        } else {
                q->tail->next = n;
        q->tail->prev = q->tail;
                q->tail = n;
        }

        q->n_elems++;
}

void dequeue_get_front(struct DeQueue *q, void *elem)
{
        memcpy(elem, q->head->elem, q->elem_size);
        struct Node *to_del = q->head;
        q->head = q->head->next;

        free_node(to_del);
    q->head->prev = NULL;
        q->n_elems--;
}

void dequeue_put_front(struct DeQueue *q, void *elem)
{
    struct Node *n = new_node(elem, q->elem_size);
    if (q->head == NULL) {
                q->head = n;
                q->tail = n;
        } else {
        n->next = q->head;
        q->head->prev = n;
        q->head = n;
    }

    q->n_elems++;
}

void dequeue_get_back(struct DeQueue *q, void *elem)
{
    memcpy(elem, q->tail->elem, q->elem_size);
    struct Node *to_del = q->tail;

    q->tail = q->tail->prev;
    free_node(to_del);

    q->n_elems--;
}
```

MY MAIN:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        srand(time(0));

        struct DeQueue *q = dequeue_new(sizeof(int));

        int t = 0;
        while (t++ < SIM_DURATION) {
                int action = rand() % 5;
                int r;

                switch (action) {
                case 0: // add random number to dequeue from back
                        r = rand() % 10;
                        dequeue_put_back(q, &r);
                        printf("t = %d: Adding %d to dequeue from its back, dequeue size = %d\n",
                               t, r, dequeue_size(q));
                        break;
                case 1: // get the next item from front
                        if (!dequeue_is_empty(q)) {
                                dequeue_get_front(q, &r);
                                printf("t = %d: Took %d from dequeue from its front, dequeue size = %d\n",
                                       t, r, dequeue_size(q));
                        } else {
                                printf("t = %d:\n", t);
                        }
                        break;
        case 2: // add random number to dequeue front
            r = rand() % 10;
                        dequeue_put_front(q, &r);
                        printf("t = %d: Adding %d to dequeue from its front, dequeue size = %d\n",
                               t, r, dequeue_size(q));
                        break;
        case 3: // get the next item from back
            if (!dequeue_is_empty(q)) {
                                dequeue_get_back(q, &r);
                                printf("t = %d: Took %d from dequeue from its back, dequeue size = %d\n",
                                       t, r, dequeue_size(q));
                        } else {
                                printf("t = %d:\n", t);
                        }
                        break;
                default:
                case 4: // do nothing
                        printf("t = %d:\n", t);
                        break;
                }

                fflush(stdout);
                sleep(1);
        }

        dequeue_free(q);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

AND OUTPUT(it must run until t=30):

```
t = 1:
t = 2:
t = 3: Adding 6 to dequeue from its front, dequeue size = 1
t = 4:
t = 5: Adding 7 to dequeue from its back, dequeue size = 2
t = 6: Adding 4 to dequeue from its back, dequeue size = 3
t = 7:
t = 8: Adding 8 to dequeue from its back, dequeue size = 4
t = 9: Adding 9 to dequeue from its front, dequeue size = 5
t = 10: Adding 1 to dequeue from its back, dequeue size = 6
t = 11: Took 1 from dequeue from its back, dequeue size = 5
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it inside of a debugger. When it crashes, it should print out the stack trace, telling you the line of code where it crashed.